# android: how do I populate custome layout when extending ListActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I need to extend the ListActivity and populate a custom layout so I do the following

```
public class BizList extends ListActivity {

String bizNames[]={"one", "two","theree","four"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bizlist);

    //ListView listviewMe = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    //ListView listview = this.getListView();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.id.list, bizNames));

/*  ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item,startDates_str));;*/

}
```

and my ListView in my layout is

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"//***have also tried*** android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>
```

but I keep getting this error

android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception: File form xml type layout resoucse ID

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. I hope it's something simple. thx agin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly for `ListActivity` to automatically find the list, the resource id MUST be...

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Secondly, when you create the `ArrayAdapter`, don't pass the id of the `ListView` itself into the constructor. Instead you should pass the resource id of a list item layout.

Try this...

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bizNames));
```

Comment: Halleluiah !!!!  I could have sworn I tried this on my initial try !!!....Jebus Christ!!!! Thank You SOO SOOOOO MUCH !!! I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add it to the resources you have to write
android:id="@+id/listView" you forgot the "+"

```
    <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

   </ListView>
```

And in you onCreate method

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

ArrayAdapter<String> myadpater = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bizNames);
lv.setAdapter(myadpater);
```

hope it works now. please vote if correct

Comment: QuestionnaireHelper cannot be resolved to a type: is what I get.....there are 6 quick fixes not sure wchich one to go with ????  What is QueHelper ??  Thanks for the help

Comment: i changed it. you can specify your own objects there you add strings so you need a ArrayAdapter<String>.